# Do configurations in Salesforce count against Storage Limits?

Tags: limits

I have a client asking whether Salesforce configurations (objects, fields, etc) count against any of the limits they impose (specifically Data Storage). I'm pretty sure the configurations themselves shouldn't, but I am having a hard time finding any hard evidence in the documentation surrounding this. Is it stated anywhere whether or not this is the case?

EDIT: To clarify, I know there are limits around each configuration (number of objects, fields, etc.). I'm specifically wondering whether they impact any of the storage limits that are implied to be for a customer's data/files.

**UPDATE:** Response from Salesforce below

> The data storage does not include the metadata. Below is more
>   information on what is counted as data storage or file storage.
>
> Monitoring Resources:
>   https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=admin_monitorresources.htm&siteLang=en_US

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm sure metadata does not count towards the storage limits, only the records stored inside those custom objects that maybe created. I doubt this is actually documented anywhere so the easiest step might be to file a case with support and send the response to the client.

Posted a link to the success community to try and speed things along, this might help:

[image]

Comment: If you go to Storage Usage in Setup you can see the list of objects and how much storage their objects are taking up, and confirm that the per-object subtotals add up to the grand total at the top of the page.

Comment: Case filed - Hopefully I'll get a quick response we can use as confirmation going forward.

Comment: Clients should accept answers on stackexchange as more authoritative than SF support

Comment: Metadata doesn't, and some "standard" data doesn't either, such as products and price books. Definitely checking storage usage is the best way to confirm what is and is not taking up space.

Comment: If it helps lend authority to this answer I work for a major ISV partner: have heard a director who handles licensing for salesforce verbally confirm this, and have heard senior R&D people also confirm it in non-recorded sessions at dreamforce.